# Google Appengine, Google Apps and Login

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, web-hosting, google-apps

I'm having some difficulty linking Google Apps & Google Appengine together to display a website on a naked domain. Here's where I am:

1. I've deployed my very simple website at http://krissytosiwebsite.appspot.com/. This website is a simple python app with one html page. Nothing fancy here.
2. I've registered the domain (http://www.krissytosi.com) via enom & Google Apps & have the naked domain redirect setup. So http://krissytosi.com should redirect to http://www.krissytosi.com.

However, when I try to hit www.krissytosi.com, I just get redirected to https://www.google.com/a/krissytosi.com/ServiceLogin2. It's as if there's some configuration which requires a 'user' to actually log into the application to view it. I just want to be able to display a simple web page though without any login.

Any ideas on what setting or configuration I need to alter on Google Appengine/Google Apps? My app.yaml file looks like https://github.com/seanoshea/krissytosi/blob/master/app.yaml. I'm not requiring a login per https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Requiring_Login_or_Administrator_Status, so I'm a little confused as to why the app is appears to be requiring a login.

Thanks for your help,

Sean

FWIW https://github.com/seanoshea/krissytosi/blob/master/.htaccess is my .htaccess file. Doubt that this has an impact on anything login related, but posting it all the same.

Comment: I did post my app.yaml. See https://github.com/seanoshea/krissytosi/blob/master/app.yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I just needed to wait ~24 hours for the settings I had previously applied to my AppEngine instance to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the login: required from the app.yaml on the root handler.
2. When creating the application, did you configure the authentication to be Google Apps.
   It means that the users need to be login with the Google Apps domain in order to access the application. You can change the authentication method in the application settings page of the app dashboard.

Comment: Hi Shay. There's no reference to login: required in my app.yaml file. Any other ideas of where this login screen is coming from?